# CloudFormation condition for choosing file from files section

Tags: file, aws-cloudformation

I've got webserver template in CloudFormation. I want to use the same template for http and https.
Idea is that I'll use condition like:

```
Codition:
  Https:                                
    Fn::Equals: [Ref: 05HttpsUsed, Used]
```

and later I've got section files:

```
files:
   full_path_apache/my_no_ssl.conf:
      content: !Sub |
        <proper_apache_config>
        No SSL config... not important now
        </proper_apache_config>
   full_path_apache/my_ssl.conf:
      content: !Sub |
        <proper_apache_config>
        SSL config... not important now
        </proper_apache_config>
```

I'm trying to combine this. So depends if I choose to use or not https it will create a correct apache config file. 
All this is inside `Instace`, `Metadata`, `AWS::CloudFormation::Init:` and `configSets:`

Edit:
I've tried also applied solution I used for Security Group:

```
!If [Https,
{CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0,
IpProtocol: tcp,
FromPort: '443',
ToPort: '443'}, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

But still can't figure it out... Either rollback (timeout) or syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need [`Fn::If`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if). Something like:

```
files:
  full_path_apache/my.conf:
    content: !If
      - Https
      - !Sub |
        <proper_apache_config>
        SSL config... not important now
        </proper_apache_config>
      - !Sub: |
        <proper_apache_config>
        No SSL config... not important now
        </proper_apache_config>
```

I also think that it might be easier to create two `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` resources (one for HTTPS, one for non-HTTPS) instead.

Comment: Doesn't work... 15 minutes and rollback due to timeout for initiating Instance...

Comment: @KamilKarczewski Your question is about setting property values conditionally. This most probably does work. You might have other problems with your template, who knows.

Comment: Awesome man! Yes In deed I found other problem in my template. After that your solution works perfectly.